# Archive Not Returning Correct Date Variable

Tags: forloop, group, archives

I'm using the technique for creating an archive that's in the Craft docs: https://craftcms.com/support/entry-archive

I'm archiving by day, so my code looks like this:

```
{% set agendaEntries = craft.entries.section('agenda').status('live,pending,expired').limit(null) %}

{% for day, entriesInDay in agendaEntries | group('postDate.day') %}
  <h2>{{ day | date('Y-m-d') }}</h2>

  <ul>
    {% for entry in entriesInDay %}
       <li>
          {# entry data #}
       </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

The looping and grouping (heh) works great, but the `{{ day }}` variable doesn't correctly output the date, instead I get the day-before-Epoch date (1969-12-31).

I don't really understand how the `for` loop even knows what the `day` variable is, so I don't know how to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `postDate.day` will output the number of the day in the month so if your entries `postdate` is 02.dd.yyyy your output is `2`. Your array index will be something like `[2, 3, 5, 12, 31]` thus these values will be converted from the timestamp into a readable day with`<h2>{{ day | date('Y-m-d') }}</h2>`. The first timestamp (0) is `01.01.1970` because of your timezone you'll see only values around this date since you convert all the day numbers from 1-31 as timestamps to your given format.

In case you did not know: the `day` variable represents only the keys of the array and with `| group('postDate.day')` you define the keys. I think your goal is to have keys like `[ 'Monday', 'Tuesday'.... 'Sunday']`. Your filter will look like:

```
{% for day, entriesInDay in agendaEntries | group('postDate|date('l')') %}
```